# JNLP Launch Error with Android ScreenCast

Tags: java, android, java-web-start, jnlp

when i try to run screencast i get this output

net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws/browser from the command line and send a bug report.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:570)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:904)

Comment: *"for more information execute javaws/browser from the command line"* What information did that produce? BTW - what is your question? If there is one hidden in the words above, please add a '?' to the end of it.